Design for circuit with under-voltaged LEDs
I'm trying to design a simple circuit for to power 3 LEDs in parallel off of a battery pack. The ultimate goal is to have multiple of these circuit with transistors that will be controlled through a microcontroller. Before I can get to that, I need to make sure that the circuit works independently first. So what I end up doing here will be copied to the other circuits (i.e., each will have its own LEDs, power supply, etc.)
For this circuit, I plan on using 2 AAA batteries in series as a power supply.
The LEDs that I'm using can operate at 12V for max brightness, or applying less volts for lower brightness. I got them from Amazon here.
My current plan is to power 3 LEDs in parallel, each with its own 100 ohm resistor. Because I'm not providing over 12V, I'm not entirely sure if I need the resistors at all. While the page I bought them from doesn't list an operating current, similar 12V LEDs have 20mA listed as the forward current. From my quick math, each LED would be receiving 30mA which has me a little concerned, but at the same time I have no idea how the under-voltage plays into this mathematically.
Here's a circuit diagram for clarity:

So far, I have tested this layout on a breadboard. The LEDs all lit up at a brightness I was happy with, which I take as good sign. However, I'm worried that leaving the circuit on for too long (I will have it running for about 8 to 10 hours at a time) will cause the LEDs to burn out or some other unintended consequences I didn't think of. Will this design work, or is there something I need to modify?

if they are '12 V' LEDs, then they already have a series resistor inside them. Which means your 30 mA figure is wildly wrong, and there's no need for your external 100 ohm resistors.

The type of 12 V LED linked in the question has a built-in resistor (you can see them inside the shrink wrap), for 20 mA this will typically be somewhere around 470 Ω, so you don't need an external resistor.
Even if they were plain LEDs you are calculating the current incorrectly, you divided the supply voltage by the resistor value but didn't take the LED forward voltage into account. The forward voltage will depend on the color, but let's take 2 V as an example. To find the resistor needed you would subtract the LED voltage from the supply voltage, and divide that by the current. So we have:
$$
\frac{3 V - 2 V}{20 mA} = 50\Omega
$$
With the 100 Ω resistors and a 2 V LED the current would be 10 mA, not 30 mA.
Using a 12 V LED that has an internal resistor of 470 Ω would give you a current of
$$
\frac{3 V - 2 V}{470\Omega} = 2 mA
$$
Which may or may no be bright enough for you. Also when the battery voltage drops it's going to get quite a bit dimmer, once the voltage gets close to the LED forward voltage they probably won't light up at all.
I would recommend using those LEDs for another project and getting some plain LEDs so you've got more leeway with the supply voltage and can pick your own resistor value. Red would probably be best as those have the lowest forward voltage of the visible ones. You might also do some research into their efficiency and brightness to find ones that will give you the best battery life while being bright enough.

Thank you! That made sense and is very helpful! I have a few spare normal LEDs that I can use to check if 10mA would light them up enough, if not I'll find some lower value resistors. I planned on having different colors for some of the circuits, while keeping all LEDs in a circuit the same color. I noticed that some colors of LEDs have a forward voltage of 3 to 3.3 Volts. Would I need to increase my power supply to a higher voltage? Also, I'm using raspberry pi GPIO pins for the control, would connecting all of them to the 3.3 or 5 V be a good idea? My gut is telling me no for some reason.

Good answer; I would just like to offer one suggestion for clarification. A "12V LED" could certainly exist without a current limiting resistor. There are ample LEDs that contain, effectively, 4-5 dies in series to achieve a nominal Vf around 12V. I admit, typically not in this package. This particular LED has a series resistor as evident from @Agent0620 Amazon link. One could likely safely assume that consumer products such as LEDs, on amazon, with a voltage rating, are likely current limited.  But strictly speaking, I would not guarantee a "12V LED" to contain a current limiting resistor.

@Agent0620 Yes, you would need to have a supply voltage higher than the forward voltage. As for connecting them it would depend on the GPIO ratings. The GPIO will have a voltage rating, current rating per pin and total current rating.

@rohmeooo Edited it to be more specific to the LEDs in question. Thanks.

Ok, so I think I found something that would work. I found some standard LED with colors I want, they have two max forward voltage of 3.1 (y & r) and 3.4 (b & g). My thought is to replace the power source with a 9 volt battery, and swap increase the resistors from 100 to 330 ohms. If I did the math right this time, that should be around 17 to 18 mA for the different LEDs.

The LEDs you show already have series resistors built-in. The value of this resistor will vary somewhat with the LED color, but it will be set to achieve some known current at 12V. Let's assume 20mA at 12V. The resistors will be:

Red, 1.8V, R = (12V-1.8V)/20mA = 510 ohms
Green, 2.0V, R = (12V-2.0V)/20mA = 500 ohms
Blue, 3.1V, R = (12V-3.1V)/20mA = 445 ohms

etc.
Reducing the supply voltage will indeed get you less brightness. But you can only go so far: as your voltage approaches the LED forward voltage, it will become very dim, then not light at all.
You propose 3V, which is pretty low. Let's see what happens:

Red, 1.8V, R = (3V-1.8V)/510 ohms = 2.4mA
Green, 2.0V, R = (3V-2.0V)/500 ohms = 2.0mA
Blue, 3.1V, R = (3V-3.1V)/445 ohms = -value, that is, nothing

At 3V you will see red and green light, but blue will not light up as its forward voltage isn't met.
Go up to 5V and you will always get something:

Red, 1.8V, R = (5V-1.8V)/510 ohms = 6.3mA
Green, 2.0V, R = (5V-2.0V)/500 ohms = 6.0mA
Blue, 3.1V, R = (5V-3.1V)/445 ohms = 4.3mA

All are usable brightness (in my experience consumer devices, indicators only need a few mA; more than that is too much.)
If your goal is to have consistent reduced brightness regardless of the voltage, consider using a 2-transistor current limiter. More about that here: Controlling High Current LEDs with an ATmega328
